# YouTube embeds on iOS safari just stopped working for me yesterday

Tags: youtube, embed

LATER NOTE...
Problem went away after about 24 hours. Reported by many customers.

---

My website has embedded youtube videos.  They have worked fine for years.

Beginning on Jan 29, 2020, my customers began to report the embedded videos not working on mobile Safari. I tried to play them on Safari on iOS 12.1.4 with the same result... they fail to play.  Works fine on desktop Chrome browser.

The following test embed code is copied from youtube with no modifications.

I've tried it at several domains with the same result:
Plays fine on desktop Chrome, fails to play on iOS Safari.

Out of the blue...  Can anyone else reproduce this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9YffrCViTVk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sg2enahL/

Comment: I experience the same issue today, it's working for you ?

Comment: When I originally reported this problem at the end of January 2020, the problem went away after about 24 hours.  It is back again for me as of March 1 2020.  Clicked the jsfiddle link above on iOS Safari, and iOS Chrome... Video doesn't play when clicked on either.  Works fine on desktop.  Tried on multiple domains.  Code is basic embed code from YouTube.  How many are experiencing this?

Comment: I got a comment on the question that I asked, someone else is experiencing the same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60513289/1399387.  double tapping on the thumbnail works..

Answer (score 0):

Just go to History in Safari. Select clear History down the bottom to clear cookies and website data for the last hour. This should fix the problem.