# youtube embed is not working on iphone ios <= 12

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

On iphone with ios <= 12 when you tap on the video embed the thumbnail flickers and nothing happens. If you click again nothing will happen. The video is not loaded.

You can try this even in the official youtube docs:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

The expected result is the video to load, there is no error shown.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but we are having the same issue.  For now, we are telling our users to "double tap" the right side of the embed code as it triggers the 10 second skip.  That seems to allow the videos to play on iOS 9 - 12.

iOS 13 is working fine for us.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I also added a bug report on the official tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150579494. Hopefully someone can fix this soon.

Comment: This same problem happened for about 24 hours at the end of January 2020.  Went away by itself.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988720/youtube-embeds-on-ios-safari-just-stopped-working-for-me-yesterday

Comment: YouTube creator support got back to us (on this issue) and YouTube has resolved the issue.